# Edit a file with PHP

Tags: php

Ok here is what I have going on.

I am listing the contest of a directory so I can edit and delete files.

The code I am using to do that is below (Other then editing as it does not work).

```
<?php
$directory = ("enctlfiles/");
$dir = opendir($directory);
$files = array();

while (($file = readdir($dir)) != false) {
  $files[] = $file;
}

closedir($dir);
sort($files);
print("<TABLE border=1 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0 class=whitelinks>\n");
print("<TR><TH>File Name</TH><th>Modified Date</th><th>Entries In File</th><th>Delete | Edit</th></TR>\n");

foreach ($files as $file)
{
    if (strpos($file, '.jpg',1)||strpos($file, '.ctl',1) ){
      echo "<TR><TD><a href=$directory$file>$file</a></td>";
      echo "<td>";
      echo date("F d Y H:i:s",filemtime($directory. $file));
      echo "<td>";
      echo count(file($directory. $file));
      echo "<td>";
      echo "<a href=enctlfiles/dodelete.php?file=$file>Delete</a> | <a href=enctlfiles/editfile.php?file=$file>Edit</a>";

    }
}
?>
```

That lists all of the files in order in a nice pretty table. The delete function works. The edit one not so much . It is due to me not knowing what I am doing I am sure of it.

Here is the contents of the editfile.php

```
<form action="edit.php" method="post">
  <TEXTAREA NAME="save" COLS=150 ROWS=50 wrap="off">
  <?php
  $dir = ".";
  include($dir. '/' .$_GET['file']);
  ?>
  </textarea>
  <P><INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Update File"><INPUT TYPE="RESET">
</FORM>
```

That populates the textarea with the file contents when you click on the "Edit" link. I don't know if that is the right way to get the data in there to be able to edit the file.

Here is the contents of the edit.php file:

```
<?php
//I have tried this but it give me that Unable to open file.
//$org = ($_GET['file']) or exit("Unable to open file!"); 

//This returns me to the prodsh.php page but does not edit the file.
$org = $_POST['save'] or exit("Unable to open file!"); 
$copy = $org . date("-m-d-Y-His");
copy($org,$copy);

$f = fopen($org, 'w');
fwrite($f, $_POST['save']);
fclose($f);

header('Location: http://somesite.com/GroveTuckey/itemsetup/prodsh.php');
?>
```

I think the editfile.php and the edit.php file are jacked up but don't know where.

I am trying to learn this and this site has been very helpful when I get stumped on something so I thank you in advance for the help given.

Also I know the danger of editing files via a webpage. This is not public or on a server that is accessible by the world. Right now I don't want to deal with a database.

I have edited files using the below code:

```
<form action="doedit.php" method="post">
  <TEXTAREA NAME="save" COLS=150 ROWS=50 wrap="off">
  <?php
  include('somefile.ctl');
  ?>
  </textarea>
  <P><INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Update File"><INPUT TYPE="RESET">
</FORM>
```

With the contents of doedit.php being:

```
<?php
$org = 'Somefile.ctl';// This is the name of the file in the form above
$copy = $org . date("-m-d-Y-His");
copy($org,$copy);

$f = fopen('somefile.ctl', 'w');//This is the name of said file also.
fwrite($f, $_POST['save']);
fclose($f);

header('Location: http://somesite.com/GroveTickey/editfile.php');
?>
```

But since the names of the files can be anything I can't put specific names in the script.

This works great other then having to hardcode file names.

Comment: You shouldn't use `include`, as this executes any PHP code that may be in the file, opening yourself up to arbitrary code injection. Instead, use [`readfile`](http://php.net/readfile) to pass the file through to the browser without executing it.

Comment: Thanks for the readfile hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't passing the name of the file back to `edit.php`. Set the form's action to `edit.php?file=<?php echo $_GET['file']; ?>`.

Comment: The form action or form method? I hate to ask such a stupid question. I will try this and see what happens. The readfile worked. Thanks for the hint on that one.

Comment: That did not seem to work. When I added that to the method the edit file could not find the file. When I added that to the action the file did not get edited. I could be misunderstanding you though.

Comment: Action, sorry. Typed too fast. Also, try adding `var_dump($_GET)` to your file(s) to see what is being passed.

Comment: Can I get an example on how to do that? SORRY I am new at all of this.

Comment: Literally, just add that code somewhere in your `<?php .. ?>` code.

Comment: So I added that in the textarea php stuff I got     array(1) {
  ["file"]=>
  string(39) "TapeBoundMedSup.MER-TLE2D_v002-test.ctl"

Comment: Is there a issue on how I am sending the data to the textarea? I guess am I starting out bad and is going down hill from there?

Comment: `<form action="edit.php?file=<?php echo $_GET['file'];?>" method="POST"> <TEXTAREA NAME="save" COLS=150 ROWS=50 wrap="off"> <?php $dir = "."; readfile ($dir. '/' .$_GET['file']); ?> </textarea> <P><INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" name="form" VALUE="Update File"><INPUT TYPE="RESET" > </FORM>`

Comment: If the file contents appear in the textarea, then there's nothing wrong with that page. Try the `var_dump` on the part where it's supposed to save changes.

Comment: `array(2) { ["save"]=> string(1174) Afp.InsertText.CodePageName[0]=T1V10500 Afp.InsertText.Content[0]=@fmt('%05d',cur_mp_in_pj)@ Afp.InsertText.Location[0]=4.25,2 Afp.InsertText.Orientation[0]=Degrees270 Afp.InsertText.PlacementRule[0]=LastPage safdsadsa" ["form"]=> string(11) "Update File" }`  That is what I get if I do `var_dump($_POST)` in the edit page.  I get the file name when I use `var_dump($_GET)`  I cut our some of the text due to character limit.

Comment: Just noticed what was wrong all along. `$org = $_POST['save'] or exit("Unable to open file!");` - you are trying to use the **content** as the **filename**. You should have `$_GET['file']` instead of that `$_POST['save']`.

Comment: You my friend are awsome! That was it! I owe you a beer or some other beverage :)

Answer (score 0):

```
El codigo para editar lo hice asi:

---Inicio
<? php

$filename = isset($_GET['file']) ? $_GET['file'] : '';
$directory = ("C:\\Linux\\www\\contenido\\"); // Restrict to this directory...

$fn = $directory . $filename;

if (isset($_POST['content']))
{
    $content = stripslashes($_POST['content']);
    $fp = fopen($fn,"w") or die ("Error opening file in write mode!");
    fputs($fp,$content);
    fclose($fp) or die ("Error closing file!");
}

?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="post">
    <textarea rows="25" cols="100" name="content"><?php readfile($fn); ?></textarea>
    <hr />
    <input type="submit" value="Guardar">
</form>

<a href="####">back to list</a>

And work great
```